# How to retrieve a comma separated list for MSAccess SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

I am having difficulty retrieving a comma separated list from MSAccess using SQL. It is very easy to do with SQL Server and I have accomplished it there. But the MSAccess solution seems to elude me.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)

SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + 
       CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))
FROM SalesCallsEmployees
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1

SELECT @EmployeeList
```

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string

Has anybody accomplished this using MS Access or am I just doomed to never getting lists like this through SQL?

Comment: The SQL above has no equivalent in Jet/ACE. There is no option with Jet/ACE other than walking the recordset and concatenating the string.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I am not sure what you mean by this in that I have previously replied that it is possible to SELECT Field & ",", which is certainly not the equivalent of the above, but I do not think it could be called "walking the recordset", either.

Comment: Well, it doesn't do what has been requested, no? Your solution can only concatenate columns within a single row, but what is needed is concatenation of values in different rows (at least, insofar as I understand the question and the COALESCE()-based answer).

Comment: Yes David you are correct, I want to take a list and turn it into a comma seperated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the fields (columns) one by one:

```
SELECT ID & ",", Other & "," 
FROM table
```

Comment: I need to select the same column. So i do "Select Name From Categories Where Category.ParentID = 1', not sure if this works in that scenario.

Comment: That will work fine, the where and select are two separate statement.